# React UseEffect with History Location Key

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, history, use-effect

I am using useEffect to render a modal if a query string shows up that contains "newcc"

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (qs === "newcc") {
            setShowPaymentModal(true)
        }
    }, [qs]);
```

Any time I click on a button for a previous modal that directs to the account page with newCC if I am already on that page it will not rerender that modal (makes sense that useEffect isn't called again):

```
<Button text="Update Payment Info"
                    onClick={() => {
                        history.push({
                            pathname: '/account',
                            search: 'alert=newcc',
                        })
                    }}
                />
```

A workaround I have found is to simply include the following in the dependency array:

```
history.location.key
```

This forces a re-render since the key changes every push.  The question I have is that this brings up the lint error of:

> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency:
>   'history.location.key'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency
>   array. Outer scope values like 'history.location.key' aren't valid
>   dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

Is it safe to simply ignore this lint error or am I approaching this situation the wrong way?  It does re-render the component.  I hate to ignore lint errors if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that your trying to capture too much logic in one place and it's simpler to manage this by separating things out.

state should contain

`isModalOpen: Boolean`

&& the render of a component should contain the logic check for pathname.

in render / functional component's return

```
{qs === "newcc" ? return newCC : null}
{...rest of component}
```

Comment: So the issue with this is when you close the modal you toggle the boolean (so now it's at off) and then when you click on the previous modal which says you didn't pay it wouldn't open the newCC modal again since now the modal is toggled to off/ the state doesn't get reset with a history.push/ but the history.location.key changes

Comment: did you try deleting the dependency array entirely? just useEffect(() => { ...content })

Comment: That rerenders constantly/ the modal is always present since `setShowPaymentModal(true)` is inside the useEffect hook

Comment: alternatively, useEffect(() => { ..content}, []) to simulate componenDidMount?

Comment: That wouldn't reset when history.location.key changes.  I think I am just going to leave it in and ignore the warning for now